# Viewing Google back-up

Tags: google-account

How can I tell if I backed up my phone to Google?  I don't know if did, but I sure hope so because I have to reset it - the phone won't turn on.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be more specific. If your phone could turn on it would be easy to tell you how to check your settings. Since it cannot you need to tell use what data you are looking for, because not all data is backed up in the same fashion. Most people have their contacts automatically backed up (sign into gmail and check your contacts to verify). Some apps may back data up to Google Drive, so look there as well. Some apps may only store data locally on your phone.

Comment: Log in to your Google account with a web browser, navigate to your settings, and request to download all your Google data (can't get on the name for that right now). Then download the archive and check. While the archive is generated, you can also check what's listed in your Dashboard, and check your Google Drive storage.

Comment: Do you have to reset it or can you flash the stock firmware onto it? You might not have to reset your device.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard in a web browser (on any device) and log in with your Google account details. You'll see a section called **Android**. If you expand it, you'll see a list of all the devices which have backed up data automatically to your Google account, and a list of all the apps with backup data and the time they last backed up.